# Domain Management - No longer able to hit downstream servers from Load balancer

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, load-balancing

I am a software developer who has an application running in production for about 5 months or so now.

The environment is such that there are three severs. WEB01,02,03...

02, 03 are application servers, and web01 uses apache to load balance the requests across the two application servers.

All three servers are connected to the same Domain.

Last Friday, WEB01 is no longer able to hit :8080 on the application servers, obviously causing Reason: Error reading from remote server when trying to access the application.

The application servers are still working properly, I can hit these directly.

I have tried flushing and registering DNS, to no luck.

Troubleshooting the network connection returns Your DNS Server might be unavailable

I cannot file browse to the other servers, but yet MYSQL replication is still working from 01 -> 02,03

In the Event Viewer, there are no associated Errors, but this information is printed

The system failed to register pointer (PTR) resource records (RRs) for network adapter with settings:

```
   Adapter Name : {D048D9A1-EBDD-4D80-8684-9FB73F9FB880}
   Host Name : NYCOEWEB01
   Adapter-specific Domain Suffix : nydps.com
   DNS server list :
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   Sent update to server : <?>
   IP Address :
     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The cause was DNS server failure. This may be because the reverse lookup zone is busy or missing on the DNS server that your computer needs to update. In most cases, this is a minor problem because it does not affect normal (forward) name resolution.

If reverse (address-to-name) resolution is required for your computer, you can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing 'ipconfig /registerdns' at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator. See event details for specific error code information.
In Server manager events I also see more info like the following.

Name resolution for the name login.live.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded. HP NC373i #42: The network link is down. Check to make sure the network cable is properly connected.
Any thoughts what could have caused this to seemingly lose its domain connection?

EDIT: I have also tried a different physical port on the server, same issues.

How do i determine if this is the NIC failure?

Comment: As you have tried a different physical NIC you have reduced the likelihood, but not completely ruled out the possible cause being a failed NIC. Given the error message, you should take a look at DNS. If you open nslookup and change the server to 8.8.8.8 can you resolve google.com?

Comment: This is a completely internal network is that advice still applicable? It does not acces outside URL, and the internal DNS servers worked before (and are still working for all other servers in a large network) @user5870571

Comment: You will then correctly have this message "Name resolution for the name login.live.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded." Did you check your reverse DNS on your server? What happens when you run a DNS test?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache on Web01?

Comment: Apache has been restarted on WEB01,02,03 as well as power cycles. Ive tested DNS in the sense I can ping WEB02 and 03 by hosname (not in hosts file so it must be reading from the domain) successfully, but still cant naviagte to file browsing, or to the app servers in browser on 8080. its really weird, everything was working fine for months, and even weirder, web01 is the master for MYSQL, and somehow still successfully replicates to both web02 and 03, which even further proves that there is valid network connectivy i would think.... Edit i cant navigate in file or browser by ip address either

Comment: Do you want to move this to chat?

Comment: Maybe tomorrow, currently this is running in a backup mode (since replication is still working) with direct access to the app servers. We are technically in a hard production freeze and my options are rather limited for debugging, and as i am technically a developer, have plenty of other coding duties to do :) I will reach out tomorrow if possible though !

Comment: I am assuming that on WEB01, the network interface card has the "Register this connection's address in DNS" checked. If WEB01 needs to create a PTR on the DNS server the zone must allow dynamic DNS record updates from WEB01. If WEB01 does not need to create a PTR on the DNS server try unchecking this box and restarting the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44046/discussion-between-busturdust-and-user5870571).